# rowwise adding columns together by column name in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have a dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(gender = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Boy", 
"Girl", "Not listed", "Prefer not to say"), label = "The term I most closely identify with is", class = "factor"), 
    int_programming = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), int_digmedia = c(TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE), int_spreadsheets = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make a summary column that for each row adds the columns starting with "int_" together. I've tried:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(any_entries = sum(starts_with("int_")))
```

But it gives:

```
`starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
```

How can I go about programmatically selecting columns to add together? I have a lot more columns than the test dataset provided here.